# Read IFrame cookie

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cookies

I created an iframe and I loaded a website in it ( i dont have access to this website - it wasnt written by me)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var el = document.createElement("iframe");
  el.setAttribute('id', 'ifrm');
  document.body.appendChild(el);
  el.setAttribute('src', 'http://AWEBSITE.com/');
  alert(document.getElement("iframe").cookie); //This doesnt work.....
</script>
```

Can I use javascript in some way to read my cookies of the iframe?

Answer (score 10):

It is impossible because of the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript). Do you really want someone to be able to stick an iframe on any page, point to any domain, and get your cookies?

Comment: i want to read the cookies of the iframe website's - my cookies - not somebody else cookies.

Comment: It does not matter. You can not do it. You can try turning off every security feature of your browser and maybe you can get around it, but your browser will be open to attack.

Comment: facebook does it in some way

Comment: Yeah, there is a way to do it using CORS (check this amazing page out: https://benohead.com/cross-document-communication-with-iframes/#Interacting_cross-domain) but you need to be able to set the CORS header on the iframe's server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to fetch cookie from the iframe

```
document.getElementById("iframeName").contentDocument.cookie
```