# jQuery alert if new cookie is created?

Tags: jquery, cookies

I'm working with a form that is hosted in an external server, the form is shown in an iframe and on submit the server makes a call to my site saving a cookie to let me know the form has been submitted, I need to know when the new cookie is created so I hide the form from view.

Is there a way to listen for new cookies and show an alert if a new cookie is created?

Comment: https://www.google.ca/#q=alert+for+cookie+iframe + http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=alert+for+cookie+iframe  and i got this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15817957/read-iframe-cookie

Comment: This library might help : http://ternarylabs.github.io/porthole/

Comment: There are no JavaScript events triggered when cookies change (requires polling instead). However, you may be able to hook into the load event of the <iframe> to make an intelligent guess about when to poll.

Comment: @MilchePatern I just checked the url, however it's not what I'm asking. The cookie is written to my domain, not an external one.

Comment: @user113215 thanks I managed to pull it out with your idea

Comment: Javascript:readCookie()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I pulled it out piecing together all your comments:

Basically there's a listener that gets called every time an iframe is updated, and then I use the readCookie() function to check if the cookie has been created:

```
$('iframe').load(function(e){
    if(readCookie("newsletter")){
        $(".suscribe-form").hide() } );
    }
});
```

Don't forget to declare the readCookie() function if you don't have it in your code:

```
function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
```